# Connection ended and command aborted in a script

Tags: node.js

I try to make a little script with node.js (v6.5.0). The first part of this script displays a word randomly found in a list. Then it uses the word (as the key) the display its value (the translation). The script requires the node-redis module. The problem I get seems related to the asynchronous nature of the functions. Is it because the first function is asynchronous that I can't reuse the argument in the nested one? I'm stucked and some directions would be really appreciated.

Here's a snippet of the code...

```
var redis = require('redis');
var fs = require('fs');

var client = redis.createClient();
client.on('connect', function() {
});                        

client.randomkey(function (err, word) {
    console.log('The question is: ' + word); 

    client.get('word', function(err, reply) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }  
        //otherwise show the value of this key.
    });
});

client.quit();
```

... and this the error message I get when launching the command **node drill.js**

```
The question is: chicken
{ AbortError: Stream connection ended and command aborted. It might have been processed.
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (...thesaurus/node_modules/redis/index.js:350:23)
    at RedisClient.connection_gone (...thesaurus/node_modules/redis/index.js:585:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> 
(...thesaurus/node_modules/redis/index.js:282:14)
    at Socket.g (events.js:286:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:493:12) code: 'NR_CLOSED', command: 'GET', args: [ 'word' ] }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call client.get(word.. ) with the variable instead of the string 'word'? Or do I get you wrong? What's the use of this request?

Comment: I tried this already, with no success. Thks Michael.

Comment: What's your data structure? Keys? Values? What's the wished output?

Comment: In Redis, for this prototype, I just put simple strings (key/value pairs). The script gets a random key and displays it as shown above. But when I try to use that key (the word argument) to get the value related to this key (the GET function) in node-redis, i get the error message. If i just use this second function (with a hard-coded key), it works with no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call the inner function with the variable, not a string. It will not work like that.

```
client.randomkey(function (err, word) {
    console.log('The question is: ' + word); 

    client.get(word, function(err, reply) {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
        } else {
           console.log(reply);
        }
        // put quiting of the client here NOT at the end of your document 
        client.quit(); 
    });
});
```

And then you didn't output the result of the second query.

EDIT: And of course you can't close the connection the way you do, as you would close the connection before the inner function is finished.

Comment: I changed the code to reflect your suggestion (variable instead of string and output via console.log for the second query. But I got the very same error message. I wonder if that's not rather something happening with the connection to redis after the first query is done without waiting for other queries to happen.

Comment: I've also seen that you quit the client after randomkey. This doesn't work as the inner function is async, so client.quit() would be called before the inner function is finished.

Comment: I've updated my answer, try it with quitting the connection on the correct position - it should work.

Comment: This is it! I moved the client.quit() to the nested query and everything works perfectly.  I understand the "asynchronous thing" much better now, with your help, Michael. Grateful!

Comment: yes, async behaviour can be confusing at the beginning. Code is not called in the order you write it. I'm glad I could help. Could you mark my answer as accepted then?