# how to create queue via node_redis

Tags: javascript, redis, nosql, node-redis

I have tried to create queue in [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis). And I don't understand how to create queue. I have tried to use [zadd](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) method. I have run example code from [REDIS](http://redis.js.org/#extras-clientoffline_queue_length-commands-with-optional-and-keyword-arguments)  and I got an error for next code:

```
var redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();
const {promisify} = require('util');
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);


client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

var args = [ 'myzset', 1, 'one', 2, 'two', 3, 'three', 99, 'ninety-nine' ];
client.zadd(args, function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('added '+response+' items.');

    // -Infinity and +Infinity also work
    var args1 = [ 'myzset', '+inf', '-inf' ];
    client.zrevrangebyscore(args1, function (err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('example1', response);
        // write your code here
    });

    var max = 3, min = 1, offset = 1, count = 2;
    var args2 = [ 'myzset', max, min, 'WITHSCORES', 'LIMIT', offset, count ];
    client.zrevrangebyscore(args2, function (err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('example2', response);
        // write your code here
    });
});

client.quit();
```

An error:

[image]

I haven't got error for simple methods as client.set or client.get. 
How to use other methods for node_redis?
I have installed redis on Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer on  my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424971/connection-ended-and-command-aborted-in-a-script);

I should call client.quit(); in next approach:

```
var args = [ 'myzset', 1, 'one', 2, 'two', 3, 'three', 99, 'ninety-nine' ];
client.zadd(args, function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('added '+response+' items.');

    // -Infinity and +Infinity also work
    var args1 = [ 'myzset', '+inf', '-inf' ];
    client.zrevrangebyscore(args1, function (err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('example1', response);
        // write your code here
    });

    var max = 3, min = 1, offset = 1, count = 2;
    var args2 = [ 'myzset', max, min, 'WITHSCORES', 'LIMIT', offset, count ];
    client.zrevrangebyscore(args2, function (err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('example2', response);
        // write your code here
    });

    client.quit();
});
```

client.quit(); must be inside of zadd method.